# Javascript/iOS - Open in

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, web-applications

Context: iPad, web-based inbrowser application

I want to display the "Open in..." that allows the user to select from a list of editors (Goodreader, for example).

Preferable, I'd like to do this through Javascript.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In don't think you have access to do that inside Mobile Safari, you can only provide the content as a download. Then Mobile Safari will render it inside the browser and provide the ability for the user to perform the Open in.. action.

Alternatively you could always write a native app wrapping a WebView that provides the ability to show a native Open in... dialog.